# Flutter how to get value from multiple TextFormField inside ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, textformfield

I have multiple `TextFormField` in `ListView`.

```
List<TextEditingController>? notes = [];
List<TextEditingController>? notesMask = [];
List<TextEditingController>? remark = [];
List<TextEditingController>? remarkMask = [];
```

and below is the `TextFormField` inside `ListView`.

```
TextFormField(
    controller: notes![index],
    onChanged: (value) {
      if (notes1Mask![index] != value) {
        isButtonEnable = true;
      } else {
        isButtonEnable = false;
      }
    },
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: InputBorder.none,
      contentPadding:
          const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      filled: true,
      hintText: 'Catatan',
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: const Color(0xFFc0c0c0)
              .withOpacity(1)),
    ),
    style: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14,
        color: Color(0xFF5E5E5E)),
),

TextFormField(
    controller: remark![index],
    onChanged: (value) {
      if (notes1Mask![index] != value) {
        isButtonEnable = true;
      } else {
        isButtonEnable = false;
      }
    },
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: InputBorder.none,
      contentPadding:
          const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      filled: true,
      hintText: 'Catatan',
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: const Color(0xFFc0c0c0)
              .withOpacity(1)),
    ),
    style: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14,
        color: Color(0xFF5E5E5E)),
),
```

My question, How to get value from `TextEditingController` in `ListView`?

I tried `print(notes)`, I got this result:

```
[TextEditingController#d4602(TextEditingValue(text: ┤Persiapan Sholat Shubuh 2 rokaats├, selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 33, affinity: TextAffinity.downstream, isDirectional: false), composing: TextRange(start: -1, end: -1))),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the result, you are getting is list of `TextEditingController` because  `List<TextEditingController>? notes = [];`. To get text from it, you can do looping,

```dart
if (notes == null) return;
    for (final noteController in notes!) {
      print(noteController.text);
    }
```

To get `notes` text as List, you can use

```dart
List<String>? notesText =
     notes?.map((controller) => controller.text).toList();
```

More about [`TextEditingController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html)

Comment: Hi, then how to convert it to be an array?

Comment: Are you trying to get all text  from controllers?  You can create another list here by appending text on looping.

Comment: Yes, can you please give an example?